# Can I install Widevine on Ubuntu for Raspberry PI 4

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, arm

I would like to view Amazon Prime Video on my Raspberry Pi 4 system.  This requires the Widevine plugin, which I cannot find on Firefox or Chromium.  Is there a way to install this plugin?

It seems the version of firefox i am running on the Raspberry Pi 4 does not include the this option. I am running Ubuntu 20.10 / firefox 84.0 -- which i believe is updated by Canonical for the Raspberry Pi. I also tried running on Chromium without any luck. I am not sure if this is due to the Raspberry Pi running on ARM processor

Answer (score 1):

The pi foundation only supports and develops the widevine packages for 32 bits because Raspberry pi OS is still 32 bit and there is not need for a 64 bit build, I will recommend you to get Kodi and the Netflix plugin

Comment: This is why I'm so happy that Apple is going ARM. Not because their ARM architecture is necessarily compatible with ARM64 Ubuntu, but because it will force everyone to take ARM in general much more seriously as an architecture. Most things work on Rpi/Jetson Nano but this lack of Netflix and Amazon Prime on ARM64 is a joke. It's been years.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, search for DRM in the settings and tick the box. That will download and install Widevine.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Note you may have to attempt to play amazon video again after the checkbox to trigger the install of the plugin

Comment: afair this setting is not available on arm (e.g. raspberry) firefoxes